# What lounge and shower options are there at Dubai Airport?

Tags: layovers, dxb, lounges

I am traveling to Nepal at the end of May on Emirates, with a fairly long layover in DBX of approximately 6 hours. I want to have access to a lounge with a shower. My arrival is set for Terminal 3, the next flight will be out of Terminal 2. How can I access a lounge with shower, and would I have to pay?

Answer (score 2):

There are public showers at Emirates Terminal 3, just look for the signs. There are multiple lounge options, but all are on Terminal 3. Terminal 2 only has one lounge, but it does not have a shower.  There are no public showers in Terminal 2.

Here are your lounge options:

- The Marhaba Lounge (paid access or complimentary on some credit cards, showers are extra).  Marhaba also operates the lounge in Terminal 2. You can [book them online via Loungepass here](https://www.loungepass.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.home).
- The Emirates Business / First Class Lounge - these offer showers and spas; but are expensive if you are not an Emirates Skywards member.  The rates are listed on [Emirates' website](https://www.emirates.com/english/experience/our-lounges/paid-lounge-access.aspx). Emirates lounge are only in Terminal 3 and Terminal 1.